# Spring + Spring Security requests are accepted only for content-type x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

this is my frist time when I decided to write application based on Spring Boot and Spring Security with full Java code configuration and I am experiencing weird problems that I cannot surpass. I am tryning to test API with Postman and my requests are only accepted when I use content-type as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*. Below I am pasting my all current configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OpenIdApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OpenIdApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
            .and()
                .cors()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }

}

@RestController
public class UserController {
    ...    

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> registerUser(
            @RequestBody UserRegistrationDto newUser, BindingResult bindingResult) {
       ...
    }

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserRegistrationDto {
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String passwordRepeat;
}
```

If I want to login I can only do this with mentioned content-type. For *application/json* I am getting 403 response status. For */registration* endpoint, if I remove @RequestBody from method parameter then it works fine with *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* request, but if I keep it then for this content-type I am getting 415, but if I try with *application/json* then I am seeing 403. I have also tried adding @PreAutorize("permitAll()") annotation above this endpoint, adding httpBasic() into Spring Security configuration - which resulted in changing response status from 403 to 401.

I have tried sending 2 different JSONs to that endpoint:

```
{
    "username":"test", 
    "firstName":"Test", 
    "lastName":"Test", 
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "password":"test",
    "passwordRepeat":"test",
    "_csrf":"8b7d4680-5be4-482a-9138-b4eb92a358c1"
}

{
    "newUser": {
        "username":"test", 
        "firstName":"Test", 
        "lastName":"Test", 
        "email":"test@test.com",
        "password":"test",
        "passwordRepeat":"test"
    },
    "_csrf":"8b7d4680-5be4-482a-9138-b4eb92a358c1"
}
```

Of course everytime I was making sure that *_csrf* matches the one returned from my API.

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Security 5.0.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that Ant pattern `"/register/**"` matches all URLs starting with `/register/` ([See examples here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html)), while you're posting to `/register` (no slash at the end). You should try either

```
.antMatchers("/register*").permitAll()
```

or

```
.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll()
```

First one matches any URL starting with `/register`, while the second matches your `@PostMapping` exactly.